# Windows taskbar recent items

Tags: taskbar

How can I clean unpinned (recent) items from taskbar? The part shown here:

[image]

Comment: Which windows version 10 or 7?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean to remove the feature entirely:
From the *Windows Settings", you need to go to *Personalization* and then *Start*.

This gives you a window with options for turning Recent Items off:

[image: Optoins Screen]

On the other hand, if you simply wish to empty the list but leave the feature:
The list comprises shortcuts held in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items`  Delete them